# How do I rewrite a single parameter using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I have URLs in the following format:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?l=accommodation/lodge/some-place
```

I would like to use htaccess to rewrite it to this format:

```
http://www.mysite.com/accommodation/lodge/some-place
```

How would I do that? I started trying to do it with drupal's htaccess file and got something like this:

```
# Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?l=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Problem is, if I enter the original index.php url, it still shows. It must redirect to the short version. In other words, this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/index.php?l=accommodation/lodge/some-place
```

Must forward to this:

```
http://www.mysite.com/accommodation/lodge/some-place
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert this additional rule above your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?l=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L]
```

This will externally redirect `http://www.mysite.com/index.php?l=accommodation/lodge/some-place` to `http://www.mysite.com/accommodation/lodge/some-place`